# Make that django simple JWT have the same permissions as Django Admin

Tags: python, django, api, django-rest-framework, jwt

I'm developing an api in Django with DjangoRestFramework, and now I started to work with Tokens, (I'm using JWT with the djangorestframework_simplejwt library). What I want is to have the same permissions that I have in my django Admin in the token, for intance, I created a group for an specific app in my Django admin but when I use httpie with an user that wasn't supose to have permissions I can get all the data.

Do you know a way to connect that permissions?

This is the code that I wrote.

```
from rest_framework.permissions import IsAuthenticated

class ArticulosLista(APIView):

   permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, )
   # All other methods
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DRF has built in [permissions](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#api-reference) (admin, user, readonly,..).

Of course you can write your own permission class extend from DRF `permissions.BasePermission`

For example:

```
from rest_framework import permissions, exceptions

class YourCustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):

    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        user = request.user
        if user.in_group('abc') and user.is_staff and user. is_authenticated: 
           return (user, None) #success 
        else:
           data = {
                'code': 403,
                'data': "Invalid User"
            }
           raise exceptions.APIException(data) #raise fail
```

and you can use your custom permission in the views:

```
from your_file import YourCustomPermission

class ArticulosLista(APIView):

   permission_classes = (YourCustomPermission, )
```

For more on how to write [custom permission class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/permissions/#custom-permissions)

Comment: This is a generic description on how to create custom permissions for DRF. It does not work with Simple JWT

Comment: @JoelGMathew yes that exactly what the questioner want, you can write a logic in the `has_permission` method to check for token in request. What you saying is from [authentication_class](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#custom-authentication) not permission_class. 2 different concepts. In permission class request.user will always be the user return from authentication class